# Dynamic URL across different environments using ImpEx

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

as a part of a requirement I have to configure the hyperlink for the description of the products across the site.

The issue is how do I configure the dynamic URL via ImpEx(as the URL points to a dynamic URL,which will be relative to each environment).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *URL* with *parameters*. Something like this-

```
https://yoursite/{param1}/stuff/{param2}
```

Then, you can read the *parameters* in you *controller* by using the `@PathVariable` in you method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a propeties on each of local.properties of every environments, example:

## LOCAL

```
target.deployment.env=LOCAL
```

## TEST

```
target.deployment.env=TEST
```

And add this code on the header of your impex :

```
#% impex.info("Target system is : "+Config.getParameter("target.deployment.env"));
#% if: "LOCAL".equals(Config.getParameter("target.deployment.env"));
$Url= LocalUrl;
#% endif:

#% if: "TEST".equals(Config.getParameter("target.deployment.env"));
$Url = TestRL;
#% endif:
```

And use this variable on your impex :

```
$Url/homepage
```

Hope this helps